# std::basic_string specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I need to override only length function from std::basic_string because it's not correct for a custom char type on a specific platform. This is current declaration for, let's say, CustomString

```
typedef STL::basic_string<CustomChar, STL::char_traits<CustomChar>, STL::allocator<CustomChar> > CustomString;
```

I need to have a class that behaves as CustomString, but with the length function changed.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `STL::basic_string`. Perhaps you mean `std::basic_string`?

Comment: @Nicol Colas, I forgot to change it, it is alias for std

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - I can see why you'd be tempted to make such an alias, but ... ewww! That's nearly as confusing as using `begin` and `end` instead of `{` and `}` and macroing `:=` to `=` to make your code look like Pascal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specialise the [`std::char_traits`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/char_traits/) structure and override its `static size_t length(const char_type* s);` function to do that.

Then you don’t even need to specify all the template parameters when instantiating a `basic_string`. The following definition should be enough:

```
typedef std::basic_string<CustomChar> CustomString;
```